# Send data to a web service via form

Tags: php, json, forms, post

I want to send data to a web service with json format, as follows:

```
{
    "request":
     {
    "t_sep":
        {
            "noKartu":"0000011110116",
            "tglSep":"2016-06-12 09:00:00",
            "noRujukan":"00001",
            "catatan":"test"
        }
     }
}
```

With the following reply (response):

```
{
    metadata: 
        {
        code: "200"
        message: "OK"
        }
    response: "0301R00105160000123"
}
```

I want to create a form to change the value of a variable "noKartu", "tglSep", "noRujukan" and "catatan".

formulir.php

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="aksiformulir.php">
no kartu: <input name="noKartu" type="text" size="25" /><br>
tgl sep: <input name="tglSep" type="text" size="25" /><br>
no rujukan: <input name="noRujukan" type="text" size="25" /><br>
catatan: <input name="catatan" type="text" size="25" /><br>
    <input type=submit value=Go>
</form>
```

and aksiformulir.php

```
<?php
    $dataid    = "10000"; 
    $secretKey = "56789"; 
    $localIP   = "dvlp.bpjs-kesehatan.go.id";
    $url       = "http://".$localIP."/devWsLokalRest/SEP/insert";
    $port      = 8081; 

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $tStamp              = strval(time() - strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00'));
    $signature           = hash_hmac('sha256', $dataid . "&" . $tStamp, $secretKey, true);
    $encodedSignature    = base64_encode($signature);
    $urlencodedSignature = urlencode($encodedSignature);

    function post_request($url, $port, $dataid, $tStamp, $encodedSignature, $data, $referer = '')
    {

        //-Convert the data array into URL Parameters like a=b&foo=bar etc.
        //$data = http_build_query($data);

        // parse the given URL
        $url = parse_url($url);

        if ($url['scheme'] != 'http') {
            die('Error: Only HTTP request are supported !');
        }

        // extract host and path:
        $host = $url['host'];
        $path = $url['path'];

        // open a socket connection on port 80 - timeout: 50 sec
        $fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 50);

        if ($fp) {

            // send the request headers:
            fputs($fp, "POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Host: $host\r\n");

            if ($referer != '')
                fputs($fp, "Referer: $referer\r\n");

            fputs($fp, "x-cons-id: " . $dataid . "\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "x-timestamp: " . $tStamp . "\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "x-signature: " . $encodedSignature . "\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Content-length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
            fputs($fp, $data);

            $result = '';
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                // receive the results of the request, 128 char
                $result .= fgets($fp, 128);
            }
        } else {
            return array(
                'status' => 'err',
                'error' => "$errstr ($errno)"
            );
        }

        // close the socket connection:
        fclose($fp);

        // split the result header from the content
        $result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);

        $header  = isset($result[0]) ? $result[0] : '';
        $content = isset($result[1]) ? $result[1] : '';

        // return as structured array:
        return array(
            'status' => 'ok',
            'header' => $header,
            'content' => $content
        );

    }


    $databpjs = '{
                "request":
                 {
                "t_sep":
                    {
                        "noKartu":"$_POST[noKartu]",
                        "tglSep":"$_POST[tglSep]",
                        "noRujukan":"$_POST[noRujukan]",
                        "catatan":"$_POST[catatan]"
                    }
                 }
            }';

    $data = array(
        'Data' => $databpjs
    );

    $result = post_request($url, $port, $dataid, $tStamp, $encodedSignature, $databpjs, $referer = '');
    if ($result['status'] == 'ok') {

        //mengubah "re d sponse" menjadi "response"
        $resultstr = str_replace("re d sponse", "response", trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $result['content'])));

        // print the result of the whole request:
        echo "<pre>";
        echo $resultstr;
        echo "</pre>";

    } else {
        echo 'A error occured: ' . $result['error'];
    } ?>
```

But the response is not as expected.

Anyone can help how to send data via the form?

Comment: so what's the response then?

Comment: 4a {"metadata":{"code":"800","message":"nokartu there is no"},"response":null} 0

Comment: I don't get what's your problem. You already got a response so I assume you already sent a data to the web service.

Comment: i want response like:
4b {"metadata":{"code":"200","message":"OK"},"response":"1801R00501170000004"} 0

this response if the code I wrote directly:
`{
                "noKartu":"0000011110116",
                "tglSep":"2016-06-12 09:00:00",
                "noRujukan":"00001",
                "catatan":"test"
            }`
not
`{
                        "noKartu":"$_POST[noKartu]",
                        "tglSep":"$_POST[tglSep]",
                        "noRujukan":"$_POST[noRujukan]",
                        "catatan":"$_POST[catatan]"
                    }`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `$databpjs` . You sent the data in a string and not in a json format. Try this.

```js
$databpjs  = array("request" => 
      array("sep" => 
        array(
          "noKartu" => "0000011110116", 
          "tglSep" => "2016-06-12 09:00:00", 
          "noRujukan" => "00001", 
          "catatan" => "test"
        )
      )
);
```

it will make a valid json format.